# Visual C++ error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-error

I'm getting an error in Visual C++ that is giving me a really hard time.

The error is error c2143 reading: syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'

My code line is:

```
coefficient[i] = (1 - (2 * depth)) + ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) 2 * depth);
```

I have #include  at the beginning of the file which should define the floor(double) function.

a bit more explanation of the variables.

double depth is a member variable of the class which this line can be found in.
int i is an incrementing index value.
double t is an incrementing value.

What they do is really unimportant, but I wanted to clarify that all three are already defined as variables of basic types.

I've gone through and verified that all the parentheses match up. I'm kind of at a loss as to what 'constant' the compiler is referring to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is the same error that the compiler is giving you, but you have to put a '*' sign in front of the second '2' so that this:

```
coefficient[i] = (1 - (2 * depth)) + ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) 2 * depth);
```

Becomes this:

```
coefficient[i] = (1 - (2 * depth)) + ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 2 * depth);
```

Comment: Ah, silly me. Can be hard to see simple mistakes without a second pair of eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Other posters have shown you the actual error in the statement, but please, split that up into multiple sub-statements that more clearly show what you are trying to do mathematically, because that function is going to cause you headaches in the future if you don't!

Comment: alternatively they could just simplify the expression, assuming the missing operator is supposed to be a two then this is a good start..
1 + (t - floor( t + 0.5 )) * 2 * depth

Comment: That (t-floor(t+0.5)) looks like a sub-expression that needs some explanation to me.

Answer (score 5):

```
coefficient[i] = (1 - (2 * depth)) + ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) (the problem is here) 2 * depth);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have the right answer, I'm going to explain how you should have arrived at it.

When faced with an error in a long expression that you can't find, take the expression apart, piece by piece, until you find it.

In this case:

```
coefficient[i] = (1 - (2 * depth)) + ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) 2 * depth);
```

becomes:

```
firsthalf = (1 - (2 * depth));
secondhalf = ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) 2 * depth);   // Error appears on this line
coefficient[i] = firsthalf + secondhalf;
```

This eliminates the first part as the source of the error.

Next attempt:

```
exprA = (t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 );
exprB = exprA * 2;
exprC = exprB * depth;   // Hmm.... this all worked.  Start putting it back together.
secondhalf = exprC;
```

Final attempt:

```
exprA = (( MY_TEST_CONSTANT ) 2 * depth);   // Error now becomes obvious.
```

Answer (score 1):

coefficient[i] = (1 - (2 * depth)) + ((t - floor( t + 0.5 ) + 1 ) **2(What is 2 doing here?)** * depth);

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar error when declaring an enum. It was because one of the enum constants was also declared elsewhere in the code.